# Jupyter Notebook - Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, keyerror, traceback

I'm new to this entire world of tech/programming. I am using Jupyter Notebook via Anaconda, it's python 3. I am stuck on one thing.

I am trying to get a value count but when I run the code I keep getting:
**'KeyError    Traceback (most recent call last)   KeyError: 'education-number'**

But when I run the code with 'age' instead of 'education number', it runs just fine. But that's not what I'm looking for, I'm looking to get the value count for education-number, education and fnlwgt. All my stuff is imported and uploaded correctly. my data file is saved as csv.

This is the code I used **data['education-number'].value_counts()**

I tried Youtube, Google, nothing. Please help I'm struggling to understand where I went wrong, and feel free to dumb it down for me.

I understand this is difficult to help me with and doesn't make sense, seeing as my account isn't old enough for me to upload any pictures to help you understand just what I mean.

If anyone's willing to help or knows someone that can help, we can message or email so I can send the pictures.

Comment: it means `data` doesn't contain any key named `"education-number"`. If doing `data["age"]` works it means that data has a key named "age". Is data a dictionary or a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Hi Sembei, the data is a pandas dataframe. How can I make sure the data does contain 'education-number'?

Comment: you are reading this dataframe from a csv file? make sure the file has this column. print the content of the dataframe and you will see which columns it has. it will have a column age but will be missing the column education-number

Comment: Thank you so much Sembei!! You are a miracle worker and I am so grateful for you! It's worked, and I really appreciate you taking the time to respond and help me! Take care!